# Create SEQUENCE such that it should initialize on every next day

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose SEQUENCE starts from "1", today it generated some sequences then on next day it should again start from "1".

Is it possible or need to find any workaround ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes: You can schedule a job to recreate the sequence.

Read here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/scheduse002.htm

Answer (score 1):

Depends totally on your database product. Default SQL has no such thing. You need to have some periodic call to the database to reset the value.

Comment: It's oracle. OP has specified at the tags

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CRON Job which can fire following command(In case you are using MySQL) at noon.

> **ALTER TABLE table_name  AUTO_INCREMENT= 1;**